# Searching for a string in many small text files on Windows Server 2012 R2 get slower and slower

Tags: c#, performance, windows-server-2012-r2

We need to grep 500k of files which are around 736 bytes.

Using findstr proved to be unworkable and the cache memory drained away, also creating many hard faults.

Wrote a c# program so I could see progress. The first time through it read around 200k reasonably fast ~1-2 mins but then slowed down to 3-7 second/10000.

Clearing the cache using RAMMAP and running again it got to 40k and started slowing to a similar speed as before.

Looking a the memory when running the c# version is fast fine, 3GB left of 6GB, the disk was high but not excessive. No hard faults occurring.

Is there some limitation I am hitting here which could be causing this. I have ran it on a different platform and OS (Window 7) and the findstr completed within 55 seconds

Thanks,

Comment: This appears to be more of an OS question than a programming question. It's probably better suited for [su] instead. (The programming relevance is your mention of C#, but your question is strictly about findstr and Windows Server 2012 and not that C# code, so any relevance disappears. It *does* beg the question, though: If your C# version works properly, why aren't you just using it instead of findstr?)

Comment: Are all your files in the same folder? In my experience 1 folder with 20k files is much slower than 100 folders with 200 files each.

Also this is probably not the answer you looking for but IMO fact that you have 500k files on the hard drive and require non-sequential access to them really asks for a change in a way you store data. If there's no relation between files I'd go for [NoSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) database.

Comment: They are split by week. The reason this came about is because the box was under scoped. This was an interim solution - hey you know how it is